# how to use multiple files/folders for python coding?

Tags: python, file

i am a new to coding and i used google colab to learn python . i started to use other services since i use a low power chromebook like repl.it etc these have the ability to add multiple files
i find this extremely common in github. how do i do that? and can someone give a rundown of what these are and why i would use them.
i would also like to learn about start.sh files and requirements.txt files i find them everywhere on github

i found the from filename import command but this didnt import the entire file i could not efficiently use the commands from here and there ensuring me that there is a disconnect for example
file:
def command():
print(list)

file ends
new file:
list=[1,2,3]
from file import command
command()
doesnt work and returns list not defined

Comment: Please rework your question. It's confusing and you don't show your code at all. The import command is the thing to use, yes, and there is a lot of [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) about it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.